# explicit instantiation: why doesn't work

Tags: c++11, instantiation

Here is a sample `code` :

**In my header :**

```
class SomeClass:
{
template <int N, typename ExtractedType>
            bool ExtractDataFromArray(std::array<uint8_t, N> &ExtractFrom,
                                      uint8_t StartBit, uint8_t BitLen, ExtractedType &out);
}
```

**In my cpp :**

```
template <int N, typename ExtractedType>
bool SomeClass::ExtractDataFromArray(std::array<uint8_t, N> &ExtractFrom,
                                               uint8_t StartBit, uint8_t BitLen, ExtractedType &out) {
...<implementation for all>        }

// instantiation for used later:
        template bool SomeClass::ExtractDataFromArray<8, int>
            (std::array<uint8_t, 8>, uint8_t, uint8_t, int &);
```

Why it refuses to instantiate `ExtractDataFromArray` for pair `<8, int>`?

`Error` is :

```
template-id ‘ExtractDataFromArray<8, int>’ for ‘bool SomeClass::ExtractDataFromArray(std::array<unsigned char, 8ul>, uint8_t, uint8_t, int&)’ does not match any template declaration
         template bool SomeClass::ExtractDataFromArray<8, int>
                       ^
```

Comment: Please finish the question before posting it, you have change the code 3 times, it's really hard to understand what you are asking if you completely change the example 3 times in a row.

Comment: The clue is in the error message... Check the argument types very carefully!

Answer (score 0):

Even though, the sample was changed multiple types, the original answer still addresses one of the issues - change `template` to `template<>` in your full specialization line. Also always mention compiler - skipping `<>` somehow actually compiles with Visual Studio 2017, while gcc complains.

Also, as spotted by @Irm29 in your now changed sample, you have a wrong signature, you are missing the reference for the first parameter. It should be `std::array<uint8_t, 8>&`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>


class SomeClass
{
template <int N, typename ExtractedType>
bool ExtractDataFromArray(std::array<uint8_t, N> &ExtractFrom,
                          uint8_t StartBit, uint8_t BitLen, ExtractedType &out);
};

template <int N, typename ExtractedType>
bool SomeClass::ExtractDataFromArray(std::array<uint8_t, N> &ExtractFrom,
                                               uint8_t StartBit, uint8_t BitLen, ExtractedType &out) 
{
    return true;
}

template<>
bool SomeClass::ExtractDataFromArray<8, int>(std::array<uint8_t, 8>&, uint8_t, uint8_t, int &)
{
    return false;
}
```